# Having trouble grabbing data from MongoDB and using in new var (Next.js project)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

Error I'm getting is this:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Here's the piece that's messing me up

```
const [user] = useCurrentUser();
var location = [user.latitude, user.longitude];
```

useCurrentUser() is here:

```
export function useCurrentUser() {
  const { data, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher);
  const user = data?.user;
  return [user, { mutate }];
}
```

I'm assuming I'm just calling it early, because it hasn't had a chance to go through the useCurrentUser() function yet. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to call it when that's done?

edit:

It's also not usable later on in a component:

**This works:**

```
<span className="bold">{user ? user.latitude : ''}</span>
```

**This doesn't:**

```
<Map location={[user.longitude, user.latitude]}/>
```

What am I not understanding, hahaha

Comment: Simply use [`async\await`](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: @ISAE Tried a few different ways to implement async\await, but once I did that, I just started getting **ReferenceError: user is not defined**

Comment: `(async () => {
  const [user] = await useCurrentUser();
  location = await [user.latitude, user.longitude];
});`  This results in **TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined** again haha. And a single await breaks the page, but that might be a good sign...

Comment: @Ladonite `data` (and subsequently `user`) will be undefined until the you get the response from the API. Make sure to check for `user` to not be undefined before trying to access its properties.